# Spring security not working for additional post url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I didn't find a satisfying answer for this issue.

I have a security configuration that has been working well until now.

I want to add one more `POST` url, that will be allowed to access by all.

While the other excluded url's are working well, The added extra added one does not work.

My code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ws/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/ws/getEvents").permitAll()// ---> While this is working
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ws/persons/createNotificationsSubscriber*").permitAll()// -->this not working
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3006/eventsMainView")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue here is**

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ws/**").authenticated()
```

Says authenticate all URL which starts from **/ws** with POST request but

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/ws/persons/createNotificationsSubscriber*").permitAll() // --> this not working
```

This starts from the same **/ws** and it is a POST request  so Spring is not allowing this

**To do your work please use this-**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ws/persons/createNotificationsSubscriber*").permitAll()// --> This will work
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ws/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/ws/getEvents").permitAll()// ---> While this is working
        
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3006/eventsMainView")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. My primary logic was to say that the last line will exclude, but now I see that it's taking the first match, like with routes.